# How to effectively use jenkins, github and send jenkins report to email?

Tags: python, jenkins, github

Create a simple python program(factorial), then load/add it in git-hub, then i need to run it through Jenkins when I make change in that python program and add it again in git-hub.Then send the reports to mail. I.I am new to git hub and Jenkins. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple. You can look at steps in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-start-working-with-the-github-plugin-for-je). For sending email you require [email ext](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin and configure it. There is nice explanation [here](https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check the link :-) And put my comment once I am done what I have questioned.